# Externalizing Statements about the Effective Topos (or: what is it good for?)

Tags: logic, category-theory, soft-question, computability, topos-theory

Say we prove some theorem constructively (by which I mean, without choice and without LEM). Then it's true inside an arbitrary topos, and in the case of sheaf topoi we can externalize our theorem into some statement about sheaves, which a "regular mathematician" might care about. See, for instance, my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378270/externalizing-a-concrete-application-of-double-negation-toposes).

I'm currently working through the details of Hyland's [effective topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+topos), which (internally) satisfies the statement "every function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is computable". Obviously the mere existence of this topos has philosophical applications (for instance, it tells us that every constructive proof must automatically give computable objects out the other side) but I'm curious if there are any more concrete ways of applying the topos in computability theory (for instance). Precisely:

> Is there a way to externalize theorems inside of the effective topos to say something about "classical" computability theory, in a way that's analogous to externalizing theorems inside a sheaf topos to say something about "classical" sheaf theory?

I've tried to work through the construction of the effective topos, using Kripke-Joyal semantics, but unfortunately I don't understand the construction of the effective topos (or indeed, the *motivation* for the construction) well enough to know what's going on "in the real world".

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Comment: The motivation is precisely to make a topos in which every endofunction of $\mathbb{N}$ is computable.

Comment: @ZhenLin -- I should clarify. I know the motivation for building the topos is to get a topos in which every function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is computable, and as I mention, I think this is an inherently interesting object. What I don't understand is how somebody, with this goal in mind, would be led to consider the construction that Hyland did.

Comment: Hmmm. I think the tripos-to-topos construction is a quite nice way of looking at it. It can be used to construct both localic toposes and the effective topos, and others beside.

Comment: I think that Section 4.2 of [this survey paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.00948) of mine is part of what you're looking for. It gives an explicit characterization of the Kripke-Joyal semantics and showcases several concrete translation examples. There are lots of examples of the kind you're looking for (though not in that paper). For those, have a look at these slides (later also turned into a paper) by Andrej Bauer: http://math.andrej.com/2021/02/03/synthetic-mathematics-with-excursion-to-computability/

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt that paper was extremely helpful, thank you! Though I'm a _bit_ upset because I had dreams of writing a similar survey one day, haha. I'm glad to see other people trying to connect topos theory with the rest of mathematics. Also, the talk that Andrej gave was really nice -- I didn't realize how far we could go by just understanding assemblies. It's good to know that statements inside the effective topos really _do_ externalize to statements about classical computability theory, and the talk had plenty of examples of this.

Comment: Kripke–Joyal semantics can be applied fruitfully as soon as you have a non-trivial class of generators. For Grothendieck toposes, one usually uses the representable sheaves, leading to sheaf semantics, and for the effective topos (or realisability toposes in general) one can use the projective objects (= partitioned assemblies), which constitute a (non-small) class of generators.